# How can i hide a row in interactive grid based on some column value?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid with a list of records and lets say it has a date column. Now i only want to show those records or make only those records editable whose month in that date column is equal to the current month on page load. Now i know that a dynamic action can be created with execute javascript code as the option. But what would be the actual code to do it? I tried to access the grid with this

```
var grid = apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
```

Then i can use the grid.model._data to get the records and loop through it and check the date column values and verify if it is current month or not, but after checking i don't know as to set the css for that particular row as {display: none;}. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i only want to show those records (...) whose month in that date column is equal to the current month on page
>   load

As interactive grid's source is a `SELECT` statement, why wouldn't you include a `WHERE` clause which says something like this:

```
where trunc(date_column, 'mm') = trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

Yes, I know - possible performance impact (index on DATE_COLUMN not being used) and stuff, but that's just the general idea. Could be further improved if it turns out to be OK.

**[EDIT, after seeing the comment]**

No problem in changing the WHERE clause:

```
where date_column >= 
  case when to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'dd')) <= 5 then trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm')
       else trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
  end
```

Comment: Actually the records that i want to fetch are not exactly the current month records. The actual query is that lets say we have February and March. Now till 5th of March i want to fetch the records for February too while after 5th of March, only the records for March. This would complicate the query a bit too much so i was looking for a workaround if possible.

Comment: @Simar, such a change doesn't make it *that* complicated that it can't be done. I've modified my message; have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1 - Create a dynamic action in your interactive grid on the column that you want 
disable

Event: Row Initialization [Interactive Grid]

Selection Type: Columns

Region: Your grid region

Columns: Your column to disable or enable

2 - On Client Side Condition:

Type: JavaScript expression

Javascript Expression:

```
//Suppose there is a function (getMonth) 
//that returns the number of the month (1..12) in a date string;
//you can do this expression.
getMonth($(this.triggeringElement).val()) != ((new Date()).getMonth() + 1)
```

3 - True action

Disable

Selection type: Columns

Columns : The column to want disable or enable

Example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:8

The column "CREDIT LIMIT" is disable when the value is 3000

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out a way to do it with javascript. :)

Comment: I've edited the response to use javascript on the client side condition. You can get the value of each cell in the column by using: $(this.triggeringElement).val()